# How to read a file specified in the PyDev environment variables

Tags: eclipse, file-io, pydev

My Project Euler setup is a PyDev project that I work on from two different computers (one is a Mac, the other is Windows 7). The file structure of the project looks like this:

```
PROJECT_LOC/
  unsolved/
    The .py files for the problems I haven't solved
  solved/
    Problems_001_025/
      .py files for problems 1-25
  ... etc ...
  texts/
    Any input files provided by Project Euler (e.g., Problem 22)
```

Every file is named in the pattern `Problem###.py` or `Problem###.txt`.

Once I solve a problem, I move it from `unsolved` to the correct directory in `solved`, which is where my difficulty comes in:

Given a problem with input, say `Problem022.py`:

```
for line in open("../texts/Problem022.txt"):
    # read file in
# code to solve the problem
```

Since I solved Problem 22 a while back, I moved it from `PROJECT_LOC/unsolved/` to `PROJECT_LOC/solved/Problems_001_025/`. Now, (not surprisingly) when I try to run it again, it gives me a no such file error.

So, *without* changing my file structure, is there a way for me to access the input text files from wherever I am in the project directory?

I was thinking I could do something like `open(${PROJECT_LOC}/texts)`, but I have no idea how to get the `PROJECT_LOC` from Eclipse at run time, and have it work on both Windows and OS X. I played with [what this person did in his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800512/use-environment-variable-in-pydev-eclipse-project-file), but couldn't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

I added an environment variable to the interpreter with the value `${PROJECT_LOC:texts}/` in my Eclipse preferences. I can now use `os.environ["PROJECT_EULER_TEXT_FILES"]` to pull the location of the input.